# Nginx redirect foreign domain to my own domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, vps

There is one strange domain that is pointing to the IP address of my server.
Sometimes DNS gets confused and it says that I am connected to that domain instead of my own.

I tried contacting the domain owner and domain registrar to remove the DNS A record that points to my machine but they weren't helpful at all

Now I am trying to redirect:

www.foreigndomain.com

to

www.myowndomain.com

so when someone types or opens www.foreigndomain.com it redirects to the my original domain instead serving my content under the www.foreigndomain.com.

I tried to add this to nginx.conf:

```
server {
  server_name .foreigndomain.com;
  rewrite ^ http://www.myowndomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

but this creates a redirect loop, I'm not quite sure why.

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect loop happens because `www.myowndomain.com` matches the same server that does the redirection, to fix this create another server to capture that server name

```
server {
  server_name .foreigndomain.com;
  return 301 http://www.myowndomain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name www.myowndomain.com;
  location / {
    #config here
  }
}
```

If you already have a server with server name `myowndomain.com` then you need to add the `www` variant to it.

```
server {
  server_name myowndomain.com www.myowndomain.com;
  location / {
    # config here
  }
}
```

Comment: "you need to add the www variant to myowndomain.com server name." - this did the trick. Can you please explain why was www variant needed in this case, if its not a problem?

Comment: in nginx (and i think most if not all web servers) `www.domain.com` is different than `domain.com`, you can handle each in a different way, like for example redirecting `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`, to use different names for the same server you concatenate them with spaces in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite variant:

```
server {
  server_name .foreigndomain.com;
  return 301 http://www.myowndomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Same thing. Redirect is happening but I get: "This webpage has a redirect loop" when I try to open myowndomain.com. Do I just put it in nginx.conf or do I create a new config in sites-enabled folder?

Comment: You can put in anywhere inside http {} section, and "sites-enabled" is preferable location. If redirect works, then rule is correct, but something wrong with other domain setup (www.myowndomain.com), I suppose.